# All browsers (including Chrome) don't refresh .css file of the page after editing! What is the solution?

Tags: html, css, browser, browser-cache

If I edit .css file and upload it by ftp to apache web-server I need to clear a cache in a browser to see the correct page.

1. Why does it happen? I think browsers should check .css file's date to decide to load it from the net or from the cache.
2. What is the proper solution of the problem for web-developers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think browsers should check .css file's date to decide to load it
>   from the net or from the cache.

Depends on the headers. The browser doesn't even need to check if the file has been modified if, for example, the Expires header had a date in the future. It's a good thing, because it spares a request to the server.

Solution for web developers - disabling cache in browser's web tools and/or constanly purging your cache if that option isn't available in given browser.

When you want the changes to go live you can change the CSS file name. Adding a parameter with modfication date to the CSS url is usually enough, like `<link rel=stylesheet" href="style.css?20130917" />`, but if you use an additional layer (like a CDN) you may need to go with `<link rel=stylesheet" href="style.20130917.css" />` and some server-side magic to map filename.[numbers].css to filename.css.

Comment: But I can't disable cache for users. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

There is a 'hack' you can use - while loading css file add after file path ?randomNumber=xxxx like:

/path/to/my/css/file.css?anything=123123

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure the browser grabs a fresh copy of that CSS file you need to change URL for that file. But that's not as bad as it seems. A common trick to to append a new querystring on the end of the CSS file with the last modified datetime. That way it only changes when the file changes.

```
<link href="/css/stylesheet.css?20131422080000">
```